# X package referred to by another package, but cant find other package

Tags: pdf, poppler

I am simply trying to install `pdfunite` which is inside of `poppler-utils`; however, I can't seem to figure out how to install `poppler-utils`.

I've tried to install it with `apt get install` and it just says that it's referred to by another package:

```
[root:7e2d33988106:/]# apt install poppler-utils -y                                                                                                                                                                                                                      4:30AM/09.12
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package poppler-utils is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'poppler-utils' has no installation candidate
```

According to another post, I could run `apt-cache search xyz` to find out what other package it's referred by, but this returns no results:

```
[root:7e2d33988106:/]# apt-cache search poppler-utils                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[root:7e2d33988106:/]#
```

I'm not quite sure what else there is to do. I've tried to run `apt get update` and re-run `apt install poppler-utils`, but I get the same results.

```
[root:7e2d33988106:/]# apt update                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        4:35AM/09.12
Hit:1 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x bionic InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                            
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]                                                        
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
Reading package lists... Done                                       
E: Release file for http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 16h 57min 47s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
E: Release file for http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 16h 58min 26s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
```

Here's an output of my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file (I commented out a few lines that had `restricted` in them:

```
[root:7e2d33988106:/]# cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep -v "#" | sort -u                                                                                                                                                                                                 4:36AM/09.12

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security universe
```

Here's my ubuntu version:

```
[root:7e2d33988106:/]# lsb_release -a                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    4:36AM/09.12
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

Are there any other ways I can get `poppler-utils` installed? I feel like I've run out quite of options here.

Comment: You have some old dependencies from outdated packages on your system. You may have to delete some packages and replace them with new equivalents (sometimes under a slightly different name) to make the dependencies work. A good tool for that is `aptitude`, but the UI takes some time to get used to.

Comment: The package [`poppler-utils`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/poppler-utils) is available for your version of Ubuntu in the `security` branch.  Unfortunately, you had this error when trying to read from the `security` branch:  `E: Release file for http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 16h 57min 47s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.`  Either that repository mirror is broken, or you have some time issues on your local machine.